# Software reset on Micronucleus possible?

Tags: attiny, bootloader

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to do a software reset using the watchdog timer on a microcontroller using the Micronucleus bootloader.  When I try it, it doesn't fully reset, as in when connected with USB to a computer, it doesn't appear as a libusb device for a short period of time.

I'm suspecting a watchdog timer reset isn't as early in the boot process as necessary for Micronucleus to wait for programming.

I'm using an ATTiny841 to make a small wrist watch for my son, and I wanted to keep it to a single button.  I've been resetting for programming with a pair of tweezers grounding the reset pin side of a pullup.  Not a huge deal if it's not possible, once I have the code set, there won't be much need to re-program.

Here's the watch so far:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkH16xzkSJM

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are trying to put the ATTiny into bootloader mode? I think you need to look at the `ENTRYMODE` [setting of the micronucleus bootloader](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/blob/0a0ae16198cf2d745d140fb10696e855ceebb0ad/firmware/configuration/t841_default/bootloaderconfig.h#L134)

Comment: Ahhh… that looks like it would do it exactly!  Thanks!   I had just been using the pre-compiled firmwares for the 841.  Looks like I'll have to take the plunge and learn how to compile my own.

Comment: I just flashed a bootloader compiled with the entry mode set to watchdog and it works perfectly!  Thanks so much, I wouldn't have thought to look for a solution there.

Comment: Great to hear. Your project already looks great. Looking forward to seeing the end result (I already subscribed to your youtube channel).

Comment: For anyone interested, the watch is pretty much complete.  You can read more about it here:

https://hackaday.io/project/163887-vlads-round-watch

or here:
https://www.hackster.io/chris3d/vlad-s-round-watch-ea1c8f

Comment: Thanks. I had already seen it come by on hackaday.io, and recognized it. Liked and Followed. It's looking amazing. Especially the metal housing. Most diy watched i've seen just add some straps, and call it a watch.

Comment: Thanks, yea, I enjoy the hardware design part as much as I do the electronics!